# How to not rollback a ActiveRecord transaction in case of failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a Model on my Rails app that has a name field in it. In the database this field has a unique constraint set against it.
In the model level I am also doing a `uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, on: :create` check.

My idea is that, after the ActiveRecord validations are done and if the uniqueness check failed then I want to increment a counter for the all ready existing record in the same table. So what I do right now is this:

```
after_validation :term_exists

    private
    def term_exists
        if self.errors.added? :name, :taken
            Term.where('LOWER(name) = LOWER(?)', self[:name]).update_all('popularity_counter = popularity_counter + 1')
        end
    end
```

This would be great but when I run my tests against it, the counter never gets incremented. I imagine that the reason for this is that everything in that transaction will be rolled back once it turns out the validations failed.

But what would be the rails way to solve this kind of problem then? It is strongly advised not to keep such logic in controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you need to create your custom before_validation method where you can check whether the name is unique and if not then update your counter and then fail validation.

In this case you can remove Rails `uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, on: :create` because it clearly does not do what you want.

I think it would be the cleanest way that comes to my mind.

Comment: But if I fail validation then the transaction gets also rolled back, no?

Comment: I am not sure about it. Rollback is done when there is a commit, but you have not gotten to the commit yet. You are just in before validation phase. And, BTW, in Rails there is a after_rollback callback, so you can always set a flag during validation, and use that flag in the after_rollback callback where you can update your counter. One way or another will work. You need to experiment with them and check the logs when fires what. I do not remember from the top of my head.

Comment: Allright, will experiment around and then see what answer to accept. Thanks!

Comment: @Kaspar, try to avoid adding logic on DB level. It is pretty difficult to recall later on what was done and where and why.

Comment: Yep, the INSERT ON CONFLICT seems tempting but then again I can allready feel that it will be as bad as DB Triggers

Comment: @Kaspar: Try what I said. If commit indeed starts during validations then you can leave your uniqueness validation, and update counter in rollback callback. But then again, you probably have several validations, and during rollback you will need to check whether you failed during that name validation and again run that particular uniqueness check manually. So, I would try to remove Rails validation and use the custom one, which would set a flag for rollback.

Comment: Solved the problem with the after_rollback method. Used a class level variable to check later if duplication occurred. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you use MySQL, you could instead try `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` (see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)). For this to work you would have to add a unique index for the `name` column though. You would not need any uniqueness validation in this scenario.

There is also a promising gem called [`upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert) (which is a commonly used acronym for "update instead of insert") but it does not yet support updating a different column (e.g. a counter) instead of the inserted values. You can watch [this issue](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert/issues/17) though.

Comment: Using PostgreSQL. Seems that to solve the problem is a bit different there.
EDIT: Also then I would need to override the INSERT for my model?

Comment: Yes, it seems that newer Postgres versions have `INSERT... ON CONFLICT...` clause instead ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)).